# How to create a subplot for each category in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

How to plot unique value in measurement i want to plot a line graph with  2 other columns from the csv file;

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header = 3)
measures = set(df['measurement']) 

for j in measures:
    x = df['time']
    y = df['value']
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not filtering your data by measurement before plotting inside the loop. See the example below using dummy data:

```
# DUMMY DATA
n = 1000 # number of rows
i = 4 # number of unique measures
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':pd.date_range('2023-03-08', periods=n), 'measurement': np.random.randint(0,i, size = n), 'value':np.random.random(n)})
measures = list(set(df['measurement']))

# PLOTTING
fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(i/2),2, figsize=(15,12))
for j in range(len(measures)):
    df_subset = df[df['measurement'] == measures[j]]
    x = df_subset['Time']
    y = df_subset['value']
    axs.flatten()[j].plot(x,y)
    axs.flatten()[j].set_title(f'Measurement:{measures[j]}')
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) is a high-level API for [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib), which can considerably consolidate the code.
- In this case, using the sample data from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77353895/7758804) for consistancy, use the [**figure-level**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) method [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with `kind='scatter'` or `kind='line'`.

  - Pass the column used to separate the data to the `col` parameter.

```py
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.relplot(data=df, x='Time', y='value', col='measurement', col_wrap=2, height=3.5, aspect=2)
```

[image]